# BX Slider CSS Code not slding

Tags: jquery, css, image, bxslider

My BX Slider is not auto-rotating. I have found the CSS code below but I cant see what is wrong with it. The website loads fine, so does the image slider and the controls work, but it just doesn't auto rotate. The website address is: https://cherwellwindows.co.uk/

```
    /* AUTO CONTROLS (START / STOP) */

 .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto {
 text-align: center;
 }

 .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start {
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 11px;
 outline: 0;
 background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -11px no-repeat;
 margin: 0 3px;
 }

 .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start:hover,
 .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-start.active {
 background-position: -86px 0;
 }

 .bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop {
 display: block;
 text-indent: -9999px;
 width: 9px;
 height: 11px;
 outline: 0;
 background: url(images/controls.png) -86px -44px no-repeat;
 margin: 0 3px;
 }

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop:hover,
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-auto .bx-stop.active {
background-position: -86px -33px;
}

/* PAGER WITH AUTO-CONTROLS HYBRID LAYOUT */

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-pager {
text-align: left;
width: 80%;
}

.bx-wrapper .bx-controls.bx-has-controls-auto.bx-has-pager .bx-controls-auto 
{
right: 0;
width: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To have bxslider automatically slide by default with no interaction, use `auto: true` because the default is `auto: false`. Here are the available options for the plugin http://bxslider.com/options

Add this code after your bxslider script tag.

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true
});
```

Comment: Should I add this in the js file or the html file under the php code?

Comment: which js file are you referring to?